# Can an alternating series be thought of as a geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, geometric-series

Can $\sum(-1)^{n}$ be thought of as a geometric series? Although we know that $\sum(-1)^{n}$ diverges by the definition of Alternating Series. Can we say that it also diverges by using Geometric Series test?

In this situation the $|R|$ value is not $<1$ so thus the series diverges?

Is this possible?

Comment: You can. I would prefer to note that the terms don't have limit $0$, so the series automatically does not converge.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes in this situation the alternating series doesn't converge but the geometric series does. What then?

Comment: The geometric series does not converge.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm pretty sure it does...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can think of the alternating series $\sum(-1)^{n}$ as a geometric series $\sum R^{n}$ with ratio $R=-1$.

Yes, it diverges because the ratio $R$ does not satisfy $|R|<1$.

You can also look at the partial sums:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n R^k =  \frac{1-R^{n+1}}{1-R} = \frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{2}
$$
This sequence does not converge because it oscillates between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Ok; one more question, is there anyway I can prove that through the alternating series test that $\sum(-1)^{n}$ converges? In this case I have to take the limit as $\frac{1}{1}$ approached $\infty$. And in that case it equals $1$. So the alternating series cannot be used?

Comment: No, you cannot prove that it converges by *any* method, because it **does not converge.**